# Frequency of less than compare algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Frequency of less than compare for below code is (N+1)(N+2)/2.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        } 
   }
```

I think N+1 is for first loop. What about (N+2)/2, any idea?

Comment: Are you interested in the number of `<` checks or in how often the inner loop runs?

Comment: yes how many times < will execute in both loop  I undestood (N+1),how (N+2)/2?

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration, the inner loop runs `N-1` times, in the second iteration `N-2` times, and so on. Each time, the `<` operation is checked once more (when the condition no longer holds), thus `N + N-1 + N-2 + ... + 1` checks of `<` in all iterations of the inner loop. In the outer loop, `<` is checked an additional `N+1` times, for a total of `N+1 + N + ... + 1` times. That sum is equal to `(N+2)*(N+1)//2`.

You can also visualize the number of iterations as a (jagged) triangle:

```
#####
####
###
##
#
```

Normally, a right-angled triangle with side lengths `N+1` would have an area of `(N+1)*(N+1)//2`, but since its hypothenuse is "jagged", its an additional `(N+1)//2` (being `N+1` smaller triangles with side-length 1), which again adds up to `(N+2)*(N+1)//2`